# Best way to initialize a python flag utility class?

Tags: python-3.x, enums, flags, enum-flags

I'm working a on a utility class in Python3.7 that makes using flags more user friendly (to me, at least)

Basically, I want to turn this

```
from enum import Flag as eFlag, auto, unique

@unique
class Flag(eFlag):
    A = auto()
    B = auto()

flags = Flag.A
flags |= Flag.B
if flags & Flag.B:
    pass
```

into this:

```
flags = Flags()
flags.set(Flag.A, Flag.B)
if flags.is_set(Flag.A):
    pass
```

To do this, I have a Flags class like this:

```
class Flags:

    def set(self, *flags):
        self.raw |= self.merge(*flags)

    def clear(self, *flags):
        self.raw &= ~self.merge(*flags)

    def is_set(self, *flags):
        return bool(self.raw & self.merge(*flags))

    @classmethod
    def merge(cls, *flags):
        F = None
        for f in flags:
            F |= f
        return F

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.raw)
```

The problem is the initialization of the *raw* attribute in an **init** method. I know I can set it to 0, but then the base for *Flag* has to be *enum.IntFlag*, and I'd like to keep it as *enum.Flag* in accordance with the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html). The same problem exists in the merge method since I have *F = None*, and then try to OR it with a flag.

If the Flag enum were guaranteed to have a *NONE = 0* attribute, I could do something like this in the Flags class:

```
def __init__(self, FlagCls):
    self.raw = FlagCls.NONE
```

But I can't enforce that, and might want to use this with other people's code.

---

1. Is there a Pythonic way to do this?
2. Would it be better as module functions: flags = set(flags, Flag.A) ?
3. Is there a better way to do the merge method without importing reduce from functools?
4. Or is it better to not use *flags and force the explicit *flags.set(Flag.A | Flag.B)* instead of *flags.set(Flag.A, Flag.B)* ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set it to `0` even without `Flag` being an `IntFlag` as that represents the state of no flag being set:

```
>>> @unique
... class Flag(eFlag):
...     A = auto()
...     B = auto()
... 

>>> Flag.A & Flag.B
<Flag.0: 0>

>>> Flag(0)
<Flag.0: 0>
```

Comment: That only works if I'm not using the Flags utility class. I can't set the raw attr to 0 in Flags.__init__ and then | or & with it: TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for |=: 'int' and 'Flag'

Comment: Wait, you're right. I can pass the Flag Enum Class to the __init__ method like I was going to do and then set it like you said: raw = FlagCls(0). Thank you!

Comment: @KurtE.Clothier: You're welcome!  Don't forget to click on the check-mark to accept the answer when you can.  :)